# creating a docker image of an app inside a running container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Ruby on Rails app inside a docker container. I am unable to create a docker image. When I run `docker build`, I get:

> bash: docker: command not found

I installed docker inside the docker container, then, still I get the same error. Kindly help.

Comment: `docker build` fails when run outside a container, or when run inside a container?

Comment: what is base image of the parent docker container? what is the result of `echo $PATH` command in the parent container?

Answer (score 0):

That means that the docker command is not in the path. Did you installed it correctly? If you want a docker container that can create docker containers you should use Docker Inside Docker image from jpetazzo/dind

```
docker run --name dind -d jpetazzo/dind

docker exec -it dind bash

root@9e6096de598a:/# docker ps
```

The containers should be immutable, you should configure the app and all the dependencies it needs on your docker image not on the containers.

Comment: The `dind` hack is obsolete now. You can just install a docker client in the container and mount  ``/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`. See https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15596